# Compiz Wallpaper plugin doesn't exist in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: compiz, 12.10, plugins

I just upgraded to quantal and once I installed ccsm and compiz-plugins-extra i couldn't find the Wallpaper plugin, among other plugins that I used to use in 12.04.  Could someone please tell me what happened\where they are?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As [indicated](http://askubuntu.com/a/205276/18612) by HDave below, this is likely a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1020830). Bug reports are offtopic here; please instead mark yourself as affected on the linked bug and post comments there which may help the developers resolve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looked all over for this plugin and at this time I am assuming this is a bug.  A rather serious one for me.  Please vote here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1020830

The Wallpaper plugin is still in the list of official plugins for Compiz as can be seen here:

http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Wallpaper

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo aptitude install compiz-plugins
```